# WEBOS LG TV: ares-inspect WARN Session#forward() failed forwarding client localPort: 0 => devicePort: 9998

Tags: television, webos, lg, smart-tv

I need to debug app running on the tv

The command I am running

```
ares-inspect -d webOS_TV -a myapp --open
```

The error I am getting

```
> Session#forward() failed forwarding client localPort: 0
> (inCnx.remotePort: 55431 )=> devicePort: 9998 ares-inspect WARN
> Session#forward() failed forwarding client localPort: 0 => devicePort:
> 9998 Session#forward() failed forwarding client localPort: 0
> (inCnx.remotePort: 55432 )=> devicePort: 9998 ares-inspect WARN
> Session#forward() failed forwarding client localPort: 0 => devicePort:
> 9998 Application Debugging - http://localhost:55430 Session#forward()
> failed forwarding client localPort: 0 (inCnx.remotePort: 55438 )=>
> devicePort: 9998 ares-inspect WARN Session#forward() failed forwarding
> client localPort: 0 => devicePort: 9998
```

Please help

I cannot find any `9998` port running on my TV

```
ares-novacom -d webOS_TV --r 'netstat -at'     

                               
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1900            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 localhost:43725         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1266            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 localhost:domain        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:afs3-fileserver 0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ssg_http        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ssg_https       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 localhost:43259         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 localhost:39547         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1979            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1088            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9922            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1602            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:dial_http       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:dial_tvapp      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1927            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:11111           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.106:dial_http 192.168.0.102:47096     ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 localhost:39547         localhost:50092         ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 localhost:39726         localhost:43259         ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.106:ssg_https 192.168.0.103:40102     ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.106:ssg_https 192.168.0.103:40056     ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.106:57364     192.168.0.103:38520     TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.106:9922      192.168.0.107:49603     ESTABLISHED 
tcp        1      0 192.168.0.106:41720     192.168.0.1:60440       CLOSE_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.106:57352     192.168.0.103:38520     TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.106:ssg_https 192.168.0.103:40046     ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.106:11111     192.168.0.107:65512     CLOSE_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:50092         localhost:39547         ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.106:57358     192.168.0.103:38520     TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 localhost:43259         localhost:39726         ESTABLISHED 
tcp      224      0 192.168.0.106:11111     192.168.0.107:65511     CLOSE_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 :::36718                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 localhost:domain        :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::9922                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

Answer (score 1):

I had installed the prod app and the local app has the same id so they were conflicted